# Facebook SDK Javascript request dialog disappearing on receiver side

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

So I'm using the request dialog like so...

```
function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
  FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'My Great Request',
  });
}
```

And being triggered like...

```
<a href="javascript:;" onClick="sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector()" >Request</a>
```

On the user side, when you click it, everything works great. It pops up, lets you pick friends to send to etc. But when the receiver logs in there's a notification for about 1 second then it disappears and nothing is there. Not sure what would cause this or why it's happening. Any ideas?

link to page [Here](http://www.thegregthompson.com/facebook/)

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this behaviour in the past.  It has to do with the requirement of needing a valid canvas app url programmed into your app settings.  Without it, you will get the 1 second then disappear behaviour.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/

> User to User Requests are only available for Canvas apps, not
>   websites, as accepting a request will direct the user to the Canvas
>   Page URL of the app that sent the Request.

Comment: In my case am building a facebook Tab App, the request is coming but when i click on request it redirect me to canvas page, is there any way to redirect it to my tab page?